# Wrong caption (As Fig. A.1.) in figure when they put in last page

Tags: graphics, captions, elsarticle

I got rule from journal as

*The manuscript (including title page, abstract, manuscript text, references, and table/figure legends), tables, and figures. Files should be labeled with appropriate and descriptive file names (e.g., SmithText.doc, Fig1.eps, Table3.doc). Upload text, tables and graphics as separate files.*

Hence, I delete all figure in my manuscript and I just put caption at the end of the file. is it right? However, when I located figure legends in last page (after appendix), the caption figure become Fig. A.1, instead of my expected Fig. 1. This is my latex source. Have any mistaken in my file. Thanks

```
\documentclass[review,12pt, sort&compress]{elsarticle}
\def\bibsection{\section*{References}}
\makeatletter
\def\ps@pprintTitle{%
 \let\@oddhead\@empty
 \let\@evenhead\@empty
 \def\@oddfoot{\centerline{\thepage}}%
 \let\@evenfoot\@oddfoot}
\makeatother
%% For including figures, graphicx.sty has been loaded in
%% elsarticle.cls. If you prefer to use the old commands
%% please give \usepackage{epsfig}

%% The amssymb package provides various useful mathematical symbols
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[mathscr]{euscript}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\renewcommand\qedsymbol{$\blacksquare$}

\begin{document}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelfont={bf},labelformat={default},labelsep=period,name={Fig.}}
\section{Introduction}


%% The Appendices part is started with the command \appendix;
%% appendix sections are then done as normal sections

\begin{appendix}
    \section{}
    \setcounter{lemma}{0}
    \renewcommand{\thelemma}{\Alph{section}\arabic{lemma}}
     \begin{lemma}
    \label{lemma:A1}
    \begin{proof}   
    \end{proof}

    \end{lemma}
\end{appendix}

\begin{thebibliography}{00}

\end{thebibliography}

\newpage
\begin{figure}
\captionsetup{labelfont={bf}}
 \caption{This is legend for figure1}
  \label{fig:1}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\captionsetup{labelfont={bf}}
  \caption{This is legend for figure2}
  \label{fig:2}
\end{figure}


\end{document}

\endinput
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From this [question](http://wiki.lyx.org/Tips/ResetNumberingOfTablesAndFiguresInAnAppendix), add this line `\setcounter{figure}{0} \renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{figure}}` after your newpage :

```
\documentclass[review,12pt, sort&compress]{elsarticle}
\def\bibsection{\section*{References}}
\makeatletter
\def\ps@pprintTitle{%
 \let\@oddhead\@empty
 \let\@evenhead\@empty
 \def\@oddfoot{\centerline{\thepage}}%
 \let\@evenfoot\@oddfoot}
\makeatother
%% For including figures, graphicx.sty has been loaded in
%% elsarticle.cls. If you prefer to use the old commands
%% please give \usepackage{epsfig}

%% The amssymb package provides various useful mathematical symbols
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[mathscr]{euscript}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\renewcommand\qedsymbol{$\blacksquare$}

\begin{document}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelfont={bf},labelformat={default},labelsep=period,name={Fig.}}
\section{Introduction}


%% The Appendices part is started with the command \appendix;
%% appendix sections are then done as normal sections

\begin{appendix}
    \section{}
    \setcounter{lemma}{0}
    \renewcommand{\thelemma}{\Alph{section}\arabic{lemma}}
     \begin{lemma}
    \label{lemma:A1}
    \begin{proof}   
    \end{proof}

    \end{lemma}
\end{appendix}

\begin{thebibliography}{00}

\end{thebibliography}

\newpage
\setcounter{figure}{0} \renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{figure}}
\begin{figure}
\captionsetup{labelfont={bf}}
 \caption{This is legend for figure1}
  \label{fig:1}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\captionsetup{labelfont={bf}}
  \caption{This is legend for figure2}
  \label{fig:2}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```